# AutoHotKey adding variables in Inputbox return

Tags: python, variables, autohotkey

The %text% variable seems to be the same as %total% for some reason. Is there a way I can have it keep its value while total becomes a new value to be used later

```
^!A::

Inputbox, text, Enter Amount

total := text += 3

;Send, %total%

Send, 230643{tab}%text%{tab}{tab}{tab}{tab}{tab}245876{tab}1{tab}{tab}{tab}{tab}{tab}%total%{tab}{tab}{tab}{tab}{tab}252620{tab}1{tab}{tab}{tab}{tab}{tab}230643{tab}3{tab}
Return
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are performing 2 assignments on this line:

```
total := text += 3
```

If you would like to have `text` keep its value, you simply have to avoid having it on the left side of an assignment.

Modifying the line to `total := text + 3` will assign the value to `total` while leaving the value in `text` alone.